# Any DAL generators that will work on .NET 1.1 with SQL CE 3.1?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, data-access-layer, .net-1.1

Are there any DAL generators or ORMs that will work on .NET 1.1 with SQL CE 3.1?

This is only for a short lived project, so cost would be an issue

Comment: Why .Net 1.1?  You can get a C# compiler for free from Microsoft.  Or use Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NHibernate works on .NET 1.1

Yet to find out if SQLCE 3.1 is supported thought